# Fixed x-position, but still variable?

Tags: position, expression, adobe, minimum, after-effects

So, I'm making lower thirds at this very moment, but there's a little thing that's driving me absolutely crazy.

There are two speech bubbles, one for the 'name' and one for the 'profession'.

The text of the name is left-aligned, the text of the profession is right-aligned.

Whenever there's a long name, and a short profession everything works fine.
But when there's a short name and a long profession; the "bubble" of the expression should be left-aligned.

For example:
*Name = Barack Obama* and
*Profession = President*, works fine.

*Name = Barack Obama* and
*Profession = President of the United states*, doesn't work as how it should be.

IMAGES:

[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5mia.jpg)

[How it was](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRix8.jpg)

This is the code I applied to the position of the profession bubble:

```
x = comp("Shape Layer 1 Comp 1").layer("Shape Layer 1").content("Rectangle 1").content("Rectangle Path 1").size[0]-250;
[x, 140]
```

NOTE: By left-aligned I mean the X - position shouldn't be less than 220… Y-position is always fixed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood eveything, but from your very last comment, replacing [x, 140] by [Math.max(x, 220), 140] should work.

Comment: That actually didn't do the trick :( And it's not connected to the name anymore :/